# Docker: how to execute commands on an already created image

Tags: docker

I created a docker image, but forgot an ENV command on the last line of the Dockerfile.

How, in general, can I run a Dockerfile on an already built image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build it again, and then overwrite your existing image

use `docker build -t username/imagename .`